# Is there an HTML attribute to tell smartphone keyboards to show special email keys?

Tags: html, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, smartphone, keyboard-layout

I notice that when using my touch-screen smartphone (no physical keyboard) that when an app asks for an email address to be entered in a textbox, the on screen keyboard is modified slightly to provide specialized keys that enter blocks of text, like '.com' or push some characters to the foreground key, like '@'.

Is there an HTML attribute or style that I can add to my HTML input boxes that will tell the smartphone/browser to provide these specialized keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm

you should use `<input type="email"/>`

it does not work on android.

Comment: Great find Keith (and Ben).  Thanks. I sure wish it was based on a name in the  class attribute, rather than the input type.  But oh well.